# Why do I suddenly have 25/16 Imperial Levels on TDS?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I was playing TDS, and I suddenly noted that I had 90 levels.  Given that there are 81 regular levels in the game, plus Panna City Medicine, I found this odd.

Opening the menu and looking at the Levels tab showed the following:

I have 25/16 possible Imperial Levels.  They do not show up in the actual tower itself.

I am playing version 1.2.2344.

Has anyone else experienced this?  Did it resolve spontaneously?  Disney Customer support is not able to help with any in-game issues (according to their email on a different issue).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because you moved an imperial level, right? Looks like a bug, but I have not found any side-effects except your total number of floors that increases.

Restarting the game fixed this.

Comment: Come to think of it, that is correct.  I did move a level!

Comment: I've seen this too...seems like lots of bugs are showing up. My game keeps turning sound fx and tips on, showing me a message about in app purchases and achievements that I've already earned.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely caused by moving Imperial Levels. I just moved two levels to test and level count went up to 31/16. Restart of game rectified count.

Comment: Yeah, it worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Exited game and problem resolved itself!  Who knows why/how, but I'll take it . . . I was going to delete the question, but I figured I'd leave it up as part of the knowledge base.

[image]